# testing with Protractor Selenium Cucumber in a maven project

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, protractor, cucumber

We use Cucumber with selenium in a maven project to automate our functional tests and Jenkins for the continuous integration,
Now we start to use AngularJS front-end in the project
I'm not sure if it's a good idea to start using Protractor ?
if yes how can we use'it in the same maven project along side with cucumber?

Comment: Protractor supports Jasmine Officially. If you are using protractor then go for Jasmine only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor is not java based. You need to use Javascript/nodejs in order to run Protractor. Normally in nodejs, there are separate task runners or build tools, such as Grunt/Gulp/Webpack. There might be a way you can leverage to run protractor with maven: https://github.com/greengerong/maven-ng-protractor

IMHO if your application is pure angular application, protractor can provide you some level of conveniences, if your application is in the middle of migration, I rather stay with what you have right now, to me, it doesn't provide much business value on migration from selenium to protractor.